# Jest don't instantiate a sequelize model

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, jestjs, sequelize.js

I'm working in an backend testing task, and now I'm struggling with Jest and Sequelize integration.

We have an existing (and working) Express JS API, which needs to be tested with Jest. This API create/read/update/delete resources with Sequelize, in an PostgreSQL database.

As I said, everything works fine in the localhost and in the production env. But, in test environment, i have some issues. Jest can upload my application into an docker container (using npm's 'testcontainers' lib), make requests and receive responses, but apparently cannot instantiate my models and repositories.

My project folder tree is something like this:

- src
- config-env
- db

  - migrations
  - models
  - repositories
  - seeders
- routes

  - controllers
  - dtos
  - middlewares
  - schemas
- services
- tests

My tests are running from /tests/integration and /tests/unit.

**My `jest.config.js` is something like this:**

```
require('@babel/register');
require('@babel/polyfill');

module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  bail: true,
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverage: true,

  testEnvironment: 'node',
  collectCoverageFrom: ['./src/**'],
  coverageDirectory: './tests/jest-coverage',
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    ...
  ],

  coverageProvider: 'v8',

  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
  ],

  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],

  testMatch: [
    './**/*.test.js',
  ],

  globalSetup: '<rootDir>/tests/jest.setup.js',
};
```

**My `jest.setup.js` file is something like this:**

```
import { GenericContainer, Wait } from 'testcontainers';

import Constants from '../src/utilities/constants';
import {
  initializeDatabaseOnly, initializeConectionDatabaseOnly, runPendingMigration, runPendingSeed,
} from '../src/db/database';

module.exports = async () => {
  process.env.DEBUG = 'true';
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
  //Multiple env variable declarations...

const container = await new GenericContainer('postgres')
  .withEnv('POSTGRES_DATABASE', 'my-database')
  //More ommited environment definitions for the container
  .withExposedPorts(5432)
  .withWaitStrategy(Wait.forLogMessage('database system is ready to accept connections')
  .start();

  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
  await initializeDatabaseOnly();

  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
  await initializeConectionDatabaseOnly();

  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
  await runPendingMigration();

  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
  await runPendingSeed();

  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
};
```

This configurations kind of works. I can upload a container and i can access my seeders data inside a postgresql database, via dbeaver for an example. So, my models and repositories are working, here, right? When i try to run the tests, i got an error in my repository call, apparently because the node process of the test don't have that instantiated.

**My `.test.js` files are being constructed like so:**

```
import PaymentOrderService from '../../src/services/payment-order';
describe('Create payment order', () => {
  it('should return error when create a payment order with invalid customer', async () => {
    let response;

    try {
      response = await PaymentOrderService.create({
        order: { //The body of request, working both in Postman and cURL requests });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    expect(response.text).toBe('user_not_found');
  });
```

But when the container process tries to create some data into the db, it crashes with a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined`. The findOne() is a function that I call to find a user and then add the payment order data into the db (with this user id as foreign key).

**We also have some tests with the following architecture, returning the same error:**

```
describe('Create payment order with credit card parceled', () => {
  it('should return error to create a payment order installments amount', async () => {
   const response = await supertest(app)
      .post('/payment-order')
      .send(body)
      .set('api-access-key', 'dreqweq-1231239-aqeasd-aqwede-fakeapikey');
   const data = JSON.parse(response.error.text);
   expect(response.status).toEqual(415);
   expect(data.error).toBe('invalid-order.config.method-payment');
```

We believe that is a jest parallelization related problem, because the same calls works outside the jest env. We got stucked with a `jest.isolateModules(() => { beforeAll() });` problem too, so we changed the jest.config.json from an `setupFiles:[] setupFilesAfterEnv:[]` scenario to an `globalSetup: ''` one, because we just needed one container running (not one for each describe). I don't believe that is the cause, but...

Someone have a clue about how to resolve this? If anyone needs more info to help me, just ask!

Answer (score 1):

have such a same problem.

1. Remove transform from jest.config.js:

   ```
   module.exports = {
   preset: 'ts-jest',
   testEnvironment: 'node',
   roots: ['<rootDir>/server/'],
   setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/server/testsetup.ts']
   // transform: {
   //  '^.+\\.(ts|tsx|js)$': 'babel-jest'
   // }
   ```

   };
2. Change all imports like

`import * as express from 'express'` to

```
import express from 'express'
```

For me, it helps. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have solved my problem actually changing some parts of the project pattern, accepting that jest and sequelize would never get along together the way it was being build. But now I got another breath!

I will test your answer soon. Thank you again!